# How to run test with Nodemon and Mocha

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mocha.js, nodemon

Hi all I have stacked with this issue which I don't  know the problem I follow to seem instruction for running nodemon and mocha here is the image attach to see more, I run
[image]

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "nodemon --exec 'mocha -R min'"
  },
```

Comment: https://mochajs.org/#installation

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha ***/*.test.js",
    "test-watch": "nodemon --exec \"npm test\""
 }
```

from here https://www.prashant-kumar.in/unit-testing-using-mocha-in-node-js/